# mail only works on the local server

Tags: php, laravel, email, send

Does Phpmailer send emails from a local server, but it does not work on the domain server.It turns out that I am sending messages to everyone in xampp, and it is impossible to log in on the server when trying to send
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8fwGq.png)

my controller with phpmiler :

```
public function send(ToRequest $request) {

        $name = $request->name;
        $phone = $request->phone;
        $phoneAndName=$name.'  '.$phone;



        $mail = new PHPMailer(true);
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = env('EMAIL_HOST');
        $mail->SMTPAuth = 'true';
        $mail->Username = env('EMAIL_USERNAME');
        $mail->Password = env('email_password');
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->setFrom('emailyandex.ru.','Запись на ТО');
        $mail->addAddress('emailyandex.ru');
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mail->CharSet="UTF-8";
        $mail->Subject = 'subject';
        $mail-> Body = $phoneAndName;
       $result =  $mail->send();
       if($result) {
           echo 'good;
       }else{
           echo'error';
       }
```

my   env on server and local -server

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=key
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL= domen 

LOG_CHANNEL=stack
LOG_DEPRECATIONS_CHANNEL=null
LOG_LEVEL=debug

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=


BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=local
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

MEMCACHED_HOST=127.0.0.1

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST= smtp.yandex.ru
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME = email@yandex.ru
MAIL_PASSWORD =  password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=
AWS_USE_PATH_STYLE_ENDPOINT=false

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

EMAIL_HOST= smtp.yandex.ru
EMAIL_PORT=465
EMAIL_USERNAME=email@yandex.ru
EMAIL_PASSWORD= password
```

Comment: Why are you using PHPMailer when Laravel has a perfectly good mailer built in? And which mail server are you using when you add it to the server? Whichever it is, it's not liking your username/password.

Comment: [Images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/90527) should not be used for textual data, such as error messages.

Answer (score 0):

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
```

set self email address

```
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=info@yandex.ru
```